# How to notify the Activity when WebView has downloaded a file

Tags: android, android-widget, android-2.2-froyo

The problem is:

my application shows a WebView for a user, and after when he has download some file I want to call a logic when downloading was finished.

I have tried to use **setDownloadListener()**,  but method **onDownloadStart()** was not invoked

Could any body say me how to handle fact that file downloading has finished?
Thanks.

P.S. sorry for my English =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setwebview client for your webview . Inside webview client u can override on pagefinsih, do ur work from there

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing in the webview

you can try running a loop in a service that checks for the existence of a file and its MD5 checksum

the checksum won't be correct until the whole thing has downloaded

when it is correct the service can notify the UI

Comment: Thanks, but application cannot know what the file user will download and obviously checksum is unknown

Comment: have your website tell your app the md5 checksum, you can pass variables to the webview via javascript injection. Your app knows the download path and the md5 checksum, have a service check that location and the file's md5 if it exists, when the file is done and it matches then it works.  If file doesn't exist, stop the loop, if file does exist but md5 doesn't match, then the file isn't done. You have to make the assumption that it is still downloading